# Prevent Asp:Panel Default Page Reload

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have this element:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="divNoPolicyId" class="divDSBox" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="PolicyIdInput" runat="server" Width="75px" EmptyMessage="Policy Id" style="margin-left: 3px; margin-bottom: 7px;" onkeyup="checkForChars(this, event)"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    <telerik:RadButton ID="GoButton" runat="server" Skin="Vista" ButtonType="StandardButton" Text="Go" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;" Enabled="False" CausesValidation="false">
        <Icon SecondaryIconCssClass="rbNext" /> 
    </telerik:RadButton> 
</asp:Panel>
```

When the input box is focused and I click enter, the page reloads. I'm trying to prevent this behavior. How I've attempted this so far is capturing the event and preventing default behavior in javascript like so:

```
function checkForChars(textBox, event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I've also tried pointing the form's default submit action at a dummy button like this:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="divNoPolicyId" class="divDSBox" DefaultButton="DontReload">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Style="display: none" ID="DontReload" disabled="true"/>
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

This was also not functional. I have seen all related questions I could find and none had a decent answer.

I am new to server side rendering frameworks. In my experience with more modern front ends capturing the event and calling preventDefault() has always worked for me.

Comment: Try using the [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) event. You can then get the `keyCode` and then use `preventDefault` if needed.

Comment: @ShawnOrr Thanks for the suggestion. If I change the event from KeyUp to KeyDown the behavior is the same. As you can see in the post my event handler calls preventDefault already.

Answer (score 0):

instead of panel could use an asp:updatePanel ? so only partial postback is sent.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pan1">
    <ContentTemplate>
          //content
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: If I replace all Panels on the page with UpdatePanels the behavior is identical.

Comment: ok... also I think I misinterpreted the question, when you click enter on the textbox what do you want to happen ?

Comment: I want to fire my onkeyup handler and nothing else.

Comment: add this aswell as your onkeyup event. onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13)"
you can also remove  event.preventDefault(); from js ... the above will register the enter key in the console but will prevent the submit/postbgack action. Hope this is what you needed